# Install Oracle 11g on Ubuntu using rpm package?

Tags: ubuntu, oracle

Does anyone have tried to install orcale 11g using offical rpm packages?

I found it is very complicated to install the oracle successfully on Ubuntu server.

And there are many different guides coming out from google. (don't know which works well).

Does anyone have some gd link recommended? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Note that the [rpm](http://download.oracle.com/otn/linux/oracle11g/xe/oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm.zip) provided by Oracle a) is intended for Red Hat -Linux (variants like CentOS and Fedora are propably also ok) and b) require 64-bit Linux to install.
Installing Oracle XE rpm into Ubuntu would first require you to have the rpm-tool in place, but after that you would most likely hit into dependency etc. issues.

In a correct environment, the installation is easy: `unzip <oraxe.rpm.zip>` + `rpm -i oraxe.rpm`

There is no use of having additional Universal Installer or such.